# Unable to process binding - knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to access a property which lies under `process observable`.
So basically `parent` is an array and I got to access the `Id` property.

I am getting the following error.

> Unable to process binding "text: function (){return process().parent[0].Id }"
>   Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined

I have tried the following which doesn't work:

```
data-bind="text: process().parent[0].Id"
```

Please help on how can I access Id.

Comment: `parent` either doesn't exist or is empty.

Comment: Is `parent` your own property or are you intending to use Knockout's own `parents` hierarchy? If the latter, `parent` is available, and if you want to go higher up the chain then its the `parents` array (note the plural) that you need to use; `parent` itself returns a single function, not an array. Unless, of course, you have declared your own `parent` array...

Comment: `parent` is own property

Comment: @user2281858 can you share your viewModel & sample data .In mean time try `process().parent()[0].Id` i believe parent is observable .

Comment: @user2281858 please provide some more code to help us recreate the issue. Ideally a snippet of your markup along with your view model. Please the [MCV docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `process` is wrapped as observable, that it has `parent` property, that `parent` property isn't observable and that it contains an element with `Id` property. 
...And also that element must not be wrapped as observable:)